# Http-Get-Function seems to be called multiple times in one call and always returns an empty array

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot

I have a RestController-class where I save submitted data (to an API in that controller) in an Array and want it to return all elements of the array when the method `getAllProjects()` is called.

I got the following Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/project")
@RestController
public class ProjectController {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private List<ProjectDto> projectList = new ArrayList<ProjectDto>();
    //...
    @GetMapping(value = Constants.GET_ALL_PROJECTS)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<ProjectDto> getAllProjects() {
        this.logger.info("========== Sending following Projects: =========");
        this.projectList.forEach(e -> {this.logger.info(e.getProjectName());});
        return this.projectList;
    }
}
```

My fontend (`TS`) does the following:

```
export class ProjectReceiverService {

constructor(
  private http: HttpClient, 
  private logger: LoggerService
) { }

getAllProjects() : ProjectCreator[] {
    let projectArray: ProjectCreator[];

    @PostMapping(value = Constants.CREATE_NEW_PROJECT)
    public ResponseEntity createProject(@RequestBody ProjectDto project) {
        this.logger.info(project.toString());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/project/getAllProjects', httpOptions).
      subscribe( (res) => {
        this.logger.info(res);
        res['projectList'].forEach( (project) => {
          projectArray.push(project);
        },
        (error) => {
          this.logger.error(error);
        });
      });

    return projectArray;
  }
}
```

httpOptions:

```
export const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })
}
```

The API is called in an `onInit`-method of my component:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.logger.info("init dashboard component");
    this.updateAllProjects();
  }

  updateAllProjects() {
    this.logger.info("Getting all Projects");
    this.allProjects = this.projectReceiverService.getAllProjects();
  }
```

The output in my Browser is:

```
init dashboard component
dashboard.component.ts:35 Getting all Projects
create-project.service.ts:22 Response: OK
project-receiver.service.ts:22 []length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
core.js:14597 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (project-receiver.service.ts:23)
```

So it seems like that array is empty. So I checked my `catalina.out` and got a little confused:

```
2018-12-11 00:02:03.598  INFO 16388 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-12-11 00:02:03.634  INFO 16388 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 34 ms
2018-12-11 00:02:35.308  INFO 16388 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] ProjectController  : ========== Sending following Projects: =========
2018-12-11 00:02:35.373  INFO 16388 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] ProjectController  : ProjectName = name; projectNumber = number; projectArea = area
2018-12-11 00:02:39.042  INFO 16388 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] ProjectController  : ========== Sending following Projects: =========
2018-12-11 00:12:10.185  INFO 16388 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] ProjectController  : ProjectName = name; projectNumber = number; projectArea = area
2018-12-11 00:12:10.196  INFO 16388 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] ProjectController  : ========== Sending following Projects: =========
2018-12-11 00:12:19.106  INFO 16388 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] ProjectController  : ProjectName = test; projectNumber = test; projectArea = test
2018-12-11 00:12:19.121  INFO 16388 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] ProjectController  : ========== Sending following Projects: =========
2018-12-11 00:13:00.895  INFO 16388 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] ProjectController  : ========== Sending following Projects: =========
```

As you (might) see I called the API only two times: Once with the `projectName "name"` and once with the `projectName "test"`. Yet the logger (and so the api) has to be called quite frequently and the attribute `projectList` seems to be reinitialized all the times. Can someone tell me what happens there? Why is the API called so frequently - and what should I do to handly that?

Edit: I am using Spring-Boot and Angular 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Http is asynchronous. So you are returning the array *before* it is set:

```
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/project/getAllProjects', httpOptions).
      subscribe( (res) => {
        this.logger.info(res);
        res['projectList'].forEach( (project) => {
          projectArray.push(project);
        },
        (error) => {
          this.logger.error(error);
        });
      });

    return projectArray;
  }
```

The order of processing is as follows:

1) The subscribe submits the http get request.

2) The return statement returns the empty `projectArray`.

3) The data is returned from the http get request and the code within the subscribe method is called. This code updates the project list.

Normally, it is best practice to subscribe in the component that uses the service. My code looks like this:

My service:

```
  getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.productsUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

My component:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(
      products => this.products = products,
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But when I add a new project and then refresh the page a little bit later I should receive at least an array with that project, shouldn't I? I was confused that I never received an answer at all, regardless of when I refreshed the site.. Yet, using an `@Autowired` Service in the Spring-Boot Backend solved the problem. For the frontend your solution is way more elegant than mine, so also thanks for that! Still I got the question: what is `tap`?

Comment: I run into the following error when inserting your code (I left out the catchError for the moment) `Type 'Observable<ProjectCreator[]>' is not assignable to type 'ProjectCreator[]'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type 'Observable<ProjectCreator[]>'`

Comment: 'tap' allows you to tap into the observable stream without modifying it. It is often used for debugging, such as in this example where it is logging our returned data.

Comment: The new error you are seeing would be hard to resolve without seeing some of your new code. Consider creating a new question with this new issue and we'll take a look.